# Looping - copy A2 (Sheet1) to B2:B8 (Sheet2), then copy A3 (Sheet1) to B8:B13 (Sheet2),, til Column A reaches blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm new to this site and registered in the hope of somebody would help me solve this vb in excel problem.

Im not that good in marco/vb but somehow can read codes. I feel that using vb is the only means of solving this problem.

I have two sheets in a workbook that i'm working, say sheet1 and sheet2.

I want to copy the value (text only, no format) of A2 of sheet1 six times into B2 up to B7 of sheet2.

Then, copy A3 of sheet1 to B8 up to B13 of sheet2 and then copy again until it reach a blank cell in column A sheet1.

Given on the limitation of my knowledge in vba, I cant provide u with sample codes as what i think this site requires. But the suggestions that u may offer will help me on the whole process; the scenario above is accurate, but not the specifics. Once i at least know where/how to start, i can do the adjustment of the actual worksheets that im doing.
Do you think its possible? Hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this site. Browsing through this site I thought there would no harm asking for the specific answers. And admittedly, i don't know vba/macro and has no experience on it only til last week that my colleague suggested that the workaround requires programming in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work I think. You'll need to change the range reference appropriately.

```
Sub CopyVals()
    Dim copyRng As Range, cl As Range, rw As Integer

    Set copyRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4") //You should change this accordingly
    rw = 2

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cl In copyRng
            cl.Copy
            .Range("B" & rw & ":B" & rw + 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            rw = rw + 6
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

**Update based on OP comments**

If you want to let the code work until the next empty cell the simplest way is update the code as follows:

```
 Set copyRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
```

Try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hello thank you your code is great. However, what i would need is to copy each cell on column a of sheet1, then paste it 6 times in column b of sheet2. The process will continue until it reached an empty cell in column a of sheet1.

Comment: That's what the code does. You just need to define the range in sheet1 i.e. if column A is `A2:A1000` then change that in the code.

Comment: One more thing, since i'll be dumping data to Sheet1, the number of cells to be copied on column A would be unpredictable. is there a way to let the code know that it've reached an empty cell then stop copying? I searched from ms support and gave me this:

>      Sub Test2()
>      ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
>      Range("A2").Select
>      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
>      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
>         ' Insert your code here.
>         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
>         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
>     Loop
>   End Sub

Comment: @ExVBANewb: See my updated post. You just need to change one line of code.

Comment: thank you! it work just the way i wanted. hopefully i can be as good as u guys are. thanks!

Comment: Like most endeavors success is grounded in persistence and consistent practice. Keep working at it and you'll master VBA.